# How can I convert a jpg file into a bitmap, using C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace convert
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg");
            // Set the PictureBox image property to this image.
            // ... Then, adjust its height and width properties.
           // pictureBox1.Image = image;
            //pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
            //pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;

            string strFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg";

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(strFileName);
            //bitmap.Save("testing.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
           pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
           pictureBox1.Height = bitmap.Height;
           pictureBox1.Width = bitmap.Width;
        }

    }
}
```

I am using the above code for converting jpg file into bitmap. It works but I need to know how to stream the jpg image and convert it into bitmap then display the bitmap image with out storing it. I am using c# and vb.net

Comment: Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(blob));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380604/c-sharp-net-convert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-bitmap-structure

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this to convert to Bitmap :

```
public Bitmap ConvertToBitmap(string fileName)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    using(Stream bmpStream = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open ))
    {
         Image image = Image.FromStream(bmpStream);

         bitmap = new Bitmap(image);

    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: this works fine.but i need to do this process in wpf application using grid view.in grid no bitmap only bitmapimages only available.how can i do that

Comment: That's good, I have not much experience with WPF but Have a look at this link https://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/61943, if it is what you need.

Comment: How do I use `Bitmap` in my program?  Visual Studio says it cannot find Bitmap.  What do I do?

Answer (score 7):

Possibly easier:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly even easier:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
```

See ref [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-drawing-bitmap-ctor(system-string)).