# How to save SoftwareBitmap object to bmp file C#, UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmap, bmp

I converted jpg image to SoftwareBitmap object, I hope it will work. The code is below.

```
SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;

            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                // Create the decoder from the stream
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

                // Get the SoftwareBitmap representation of the file
                softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();


            }
```

So I do not know now how to make .bmp file using this softwareBitmap.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [C# .NET Convert a JPEG Image into a Bitmap structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380604/c-sharp-net-convert-a-jpeg-image-into-a-bitmap-structure)

Answer (score -1):

Use [Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead:

```
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
    bmp.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```